# Finding deployed Google Tag Manager server-side version in GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I've recently joined a new company which already has a version of Google Tag Manager server-side up and running. I am new to Google Cloud Platform (GCP), and I have not been able to find the supposed docker image in the image repository for our account. Or, at least I am trying to figure out how to check if there is one and how do I correlate its digest to what image we've deployed that is located at [gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image](https://gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image).

I've tried deploying it both automatically provisioned in my own cloud account and also running the manual steps and got it working. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to check which version we have deployed at our company as it is already live.

I suspect it is quite a bit of an old version (unless it auto-updates?), seeing as the GTM server-side docker repository has had frequent updates.

Being new to the whole container imaging with docker, I figured I could use Cloud shell to check it that way, but it seems when setting up the specific Appengine instance with the shell script provided (located [here](https://googletagmanager.com/static/serverjs/setup.sh)), it doesn't really "load" a docker image as if you'd deployed it yourself. At least I don't think so, because I can't find any info using docker commands in the Cloud shell of said GCP project running the flexible Appengine environment.

Any guidance on how to find out which version of GTM server-side is running in our Appengine instance?

[image: How can I figure out which image is deployed?]

Comment: Have you already checked the App Engine page in GCP? If not, you can find it in the Navigation menu -> App Engine -> Versions tab. sample screenshot https://imgur.com/a/X7VEHgS

Comment: Yes. It is upgraded to production/flexible environments. I am trying to learn which docker image is deployed, but don't know how to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

To check what docker images your **App Engine Flex** uses is by [ssh to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/ssh). To ssh to your **App Engine instances** is by going to the **instance tab** then choosing the correct `service` and `version` then click the `ssh button` or you can access it by using this gcloud command on your terminal or cloud shell:

`gcloud app instances ssh "INSTANCE_ID" --service "SERVICE_NAME" --version "VERSION_ID" --project "PROJECT_ID"`

Once you have successfully ssh to your instance, run `docker images` command to list your docker images

[image]

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot in my understanding of how this works. The image ID provided when running docker images after SSH:ing, it is not the same as the docker image name in gtm-cloud-image website, such as cf9fc.. for the most recent one. I figured that name would be the same as IMAGE ID. My docker images command returns:

REP: gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image, TAG: <none>, IMAGE ID: 3aa60af41648, CREATED: 2 months ago, SIZE: 326MB.

I was hoping to find that the IMAGE ID was in the list on in either NAME or have a tag, so I know what was deployed.